# how will be the body of the recurring order for paypal checkout api

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paypal

I have a rails application and now im trying to integrate with the Paypal for subscription.

I did a successful checkout with a single non recuring product using paypal checkout api.
My body for the order was

```
body = {
        intent: 'CAPTURE',
        application_context: {
            return_url: "#{Rails.application.secrets.app_host}#{return_path}",
            cancel_url: "#{Rails.application.secrets.app_host}#{cancel_path}"
        },
        purchase_units: [
            {
              amount: {
                  currency_code: 'USD',
                    value: '220.00'
                  }
            }
        ]
    }
```

I have my required plan saved in db:

```
#<Plan id: 6, name: "Daimond", fee: 45, created_at: "2019-08-19 08:40:13", updated_at: "2019-10-11 03:42:26", recuring: true, period: "Month", cycles: 12>
```

How will be the body for this kind of recurring orders?

Answer (score 0):

Once you have a Plan, subscriptions need to be approved by the payer. The best way to get that approval is discussed in Step 4 here: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/subscriptions/integrate/#4-create-a-subscription

Comment: But this is using api . I was using SDK.

Comment: The new Subscriptions API: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/subscriptions/v1/ , is not supported by any of the PayPal SDKs. You must use a direct api integration for product/plan creation, and smart payment buttons is recommended for approval (vs an old-style redirect integration)